# Redirect www.subdomain domain mask to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

I currently have subdomain.example.com as a domain mask for my website, using a CNAME record in my DNS settings. The website it is masking (lets call it mask.external.com) recognizes subdomain.example.com on its server and gives us a specific page.

My issue is that www.subdomain.example.com was bringing up a 404 'page not found', and after adding a CNAME record making www.subdomain.example.com as a second domain mask for mask.external.com, would simply give us a general page (not tailored to our website).

I was wondering if there was anything we could add (DNS records, .htaccess, etc) that would redirect www.subdomain.example.com to subdomain.example.com BEFORE it tried to visit this external service, so that we could properly serve it to users who type www.subdomain.example.com

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have cpanel then there might be an option in your cpanel to redirect subdomains to domain with and without a prefix "www".

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. Thanks for the suggestion though!